# How I can use SoundPool in SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview, soundpool

I have this structure:

1) main activity:

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    setContentView(new GameView(this));

}
```

2) game view

```
SoundPool sp;
int mySound = 0;    

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    sp = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    mySound = sp.load(this, R.raw.mysound, 1);      

}
```

On line "mySound = sp.load(this, R.raw.mysound, 1);" it gives me error - "The method load(Context, int, int) in the type SoundPool is not applicable for the arguments (GameView, int, int)". Guys, how can i fix it? When I use "extends Activity" it works ok, but in SurfaceView it doesn't work. Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to pass the context like so:

```
mySound = sp.load(context, R.raw.mysound, 1);
```